# getting error while pushing changes to master branch in a git repository

Tags: git

> How can I give write permission to read-only file in git
>   repository.Because of read only permission I'm getting error like
>   "Attempting to modify read-only file"
>
> ! [remote rejected]
>
> [error message 1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/50nJ7.png
>
> [error message 2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPQqS.png
>
> [error message 3] https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LVMu.png
>
> I don't have admin access to `repo`, but I can push other changes to
>   master branch. remote `repo` is having 3 read only files and same
>   `repo` is cloned to my local machine and by mistake read only files
>   got affected and now I'm unable to push changes due to this error.
>   Please help me to give write permissions to the read only files.kindly
>   refer the image link for error details and get back me the
>   solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the entire error message?

Comment: Do you have admin access to the repo? If not, common practice is to fork the repo and then create a Pull Request from that fork to the original repo.

Comment: Error message  is updated.Kindly look into those and let me know if there are any possible solution

Comment: Error message  is updated.Kindly look into those and let me know if there are any possible solution

Comment: **Did you read the error message?** It says: "Attempting to modify read only files: .check.sh", you have modified this file, but a pre-receive hook on the remote forbids you from pushing commits that does so, so you need to rewrite your commits locally so that you're not modifying this file, before you can push. And no, it will not be enough to simply add another commit that restores the file, the commits you try to push must not modify this file, at all.

Comment: Git doesn't have a notion of "read only files". It is wholely the pre-receive hook on the server that forbids you from doing it, in that it detects a commit that changes that file and then rejects the push. There is nothing we, here, can do with this. You will either have to change your commits so that you're not modifying this file, or you will have to talk to the owner of that repository to get him/her to lift that restriction. You cannot circumvent this and there's nothing we can tell you that will let you circumvent it.

Comment: Is there any option to change pre-receive hook from my side,so that changes can be pushed.

Comment: How to enable my custom pre-receive hook?